How to get a faster API response in Selenium?
I am developing a bot in selenium which selects a date from calender whenerver it gets green during the day when the date gets green the bot selects it and then load the rest of page to enter the info. But the problem is that date gets green for only 2 seconds and after selecting a date there is a request generated to server that takes 3 seconds to respond due to which my bots gives an error after selecting the date as the date gets back red even before the response of the API. How can i solve this problem so that bot can go through date selecting procedure in less than 2 seconds instead of 3 seconds?
I have tried implicit and explicit wait but that is not working

you'd need to make the backend server respond faster or possibly improve your own internet speed.  (there's nothing you can do with Selenium to speed up requests/responses to/from the server)
